# How to choose a MOSFET driver?

Tags: mosfet-driver, powermosfet

What do you look for in a MOSFET driver before choosing it to switch a certain MOSFET? Am reading through the driver datasheet and cant precisely understand what is the ability limit of this driver.

For example, am using a [BUK7K89-100E](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/916/BUK7K89_100E-2937815.pdf) (100V, 13A dual n-channel mos) in a full-bridge circuit.

Trying to figure out if the [MIC4606](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/268/MIC4606_85V_Full_Bridge_MOSFET_Drivers_Adaptive_De-2853764.pdf) driver can actually switch it. The driver receives a PWM signal from a µ-controller to switch on and off.

Switching frequency max= 20kHz. Driver supply voltage =12v. Mosfet supply (Drain) voltage = 24V.

Any guidelines that are recommended for this type of process?

Comment: What switching frequency are you looking for? Supply voltage (logic and power)? Does it need to be fully static, or can it be bootstrap?

Comment: Switching frequency max= 20kHz. Driver supply voltage =12v. Mosfet supply voltage = 24V. Not clear if it needs to be full static or bootstrap.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on how quickly you need to switch the FETs.

The BUK7K89-100E requires about 5 nC of gate charge. This is (very approximately) 1000 pF. The MIC4606 can drive 1000 pF in 20 ns. If this is sufficient for your switching speed, it will work.

Comment: Thank you jp314. Any guide lines that you would recommend?

Comment: 13.6nC (total)? At Vgs(on) = 10V, this is effectively an "average capacitance" of 1.36nF.  Using an average equivalent, or the charge, always seemed reasonable to me.

Answer (score 2):

> What do you look for in a MOSFET driver before choosing it to switch a certain MOSFET?

- Do I really need a MOSFET driver? Can a totem-pole be suitable instead?
- What do I need? A half-bridge or a single-ended driver?
- Do I need isolation? Can I use a gate drive transformer or should I go for isolated gate drive chip?
- (For half-bridge drivers) Can the driver chip generate dead times or should I manage dead time generation externally? (Not always a reason for preference but sometimes it's needed)
- What is the maximum switching frequency? What rise and fall times are acceptable?
- (Most important part) What peak current do I need? Can the pre-driver in the driver chip withstand these peak currents during switching?